# Add Datatable to Existing Excel Spreadsheet vbnet, always Corrupt

Tags: excel, vb.net, datatable, spreadsheet

UPDATED:
Appeared to be something with the SHEETID, now its finding additional worksheets when working with the USING tag instead in combo with this sheetid finder.

```
    Dim sheetId As UInteger = 1
    If (sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Count > 0) Then
        sheetId = CUInt(sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Select(Function(s) s.SheetId.Value).Max + 1)
    End If
```

Here is the code i used to make it work, stopped corrupting the file now:

```
' Given a document name, inserts a new worksheet.
Public Sub InsertWorksheet(ByVal docName As String, ByVal SQL As DataTable, ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal intSheetId As Integer)
    'Dim sheetName As String
    Dim fileName As String = docName
    ' Open an existing spreadsheet document for editing.
    Dim spreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, True)
    Using (spreadSheet)
        ' Add a blank WorksheetPart.
        Dim newWorksheetPart As WorksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(New SheetData())

        ' Create a Sheets object.
        Dim sheets As Sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of Sheets)()
        Dim relationshipId As String = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart)

        ' Get a unique ID for the new worksheet.
        Dim sheetId As UInteger = 1
        If (sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Count > 0) Then
            sheetId = CUInt(sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Select(Function(s) s.SheetId.Value).Max + 1)
        End If

        ' Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
        sheet.Id = relationshipId
        sheet.SheetId = sheetId
        sheet.Name = sheetName
        sheets.Append(sheet)

        'get the sheetData object so we can add the data table to it
        Dim sheetData As SheetData = newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()

        'add the data table
        AddDataTable(SQL, sheetData)

        'save the workbook
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()

        ' Close the document.
        spreadSheet.Close()

    End Using

End Sub
```

---

File is always corrupt after creating, trying to create a spreadsheet with 4 workbooks with separate data loaded via data tables.  File size looks to be valid and I dont get any specific errors when creating the file.  Just won't open the excel sheet after creating the file.

Existing code to call functions:

```
    Try
        CreateExcelFileFromDataTable(iExcelFileLoc & ExportFileName, iAGetTable)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ExceptionType As Integer = Type.GetTypeCode(ex.GetType())
        LogMessage(strAppName & "  - Failure : " & iExcelFileLoc & ExportFileName & "  Error:'" & ex.Message & "'  Error Type:'" & CStr(ExceptionType) & "'  Trace:" & ex.StackTrace, TraceEventType.Error)


    End Try

    Dim iBGetTable As DataTable = GetDataTable(SQL_SELECT_DOCUMENTS_TO_FOR_DOCS_NOT_FOUND_IN_DOCNUMS)
    Dim iReportB As String = BuildReportHTML(iBGetTable)
    InsertWorksheet(iExcelFileLoc & ExportFileName, iBGetTable, "Missing Scanned Documents", 2)

    ' ======================================================================
```

Both functions to create excel initially and then a function to add a new worksheet with datatable to the existing spreadsheet.

---

```
Public Sub InsertWorksheet(ByVal docName As String, ByVal SQL As DataTable, ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal intSheetId As Integer)

    Dim iFinalSheetName As String = ""



    Dim spreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, True)


    Dim newWorksheetPart As WorksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(New SheetData())

    ' Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Dim sheets As Sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(Of Sheets)(New Sheets())
    Dim relationshipId As String = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart)
    ' Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.

    Dim sheetId As UInteger = 1
    If (sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Count > 0) Then
        sheetId = CUInt(sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Select(Function(s) s.SheetId.Value).Max + 1)
    End If

    iFinalSheetName = (sheetName.ToString())

    ' Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
    sheet.Id = relationshipId
    sheet.SheetId = CType(intSheetId, UInt32Value)
    sheet.Name = iFinalSheetName
    sheets.Append(sheet)

    'get the sheetData object so we can add the data table to it
    Dim sheetData As SheetData = newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()

    'add the data table
    AddDataTable(SQL, sheetData)

    'save the workbook
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()

    ' Close the document.
    spreadSheet.Close()

End Sub


Public Sub CreateExcelFileFromDataTable(ByVal FilePath As String, myDT As DataTable)

    ' Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
    ' By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    Dim spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = spreadsheetDocument.Create(FilePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)

    ' Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    Dim workbookpart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart
    workbookpart.Workbook = New Workbook

    ' Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(New SheetData())

    ' Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Dim sheets As Sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(Of Sheets)(New Sheets())

    ' Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
    sheet.Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
    sheet.SheetId = 1
    sheet.Name = "Duplicate Document"

    sheets.Append(sheet)

    'get the sheetData object so we can add the data table to it
    Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()

    'add the data table
    'AddDataTable(myDT, sheetData)

    'save the workbook
    workbookpart.Workbook.Save()

    ' Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close()

    ' -----------------------------------

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for you:

1. Create a sample of the spreadsheet manually.
2. Download and Install the Open XML SDK tool
3. Open the spreadsheet in the tool
4. Once the spreadsheet is opened, there's a section where you can view .NET source code to create a sheet that looks like it.

I use the tool a lot.  Working with the Office XML SDK without it can be very cumbersome.